AWS - Push an event to all Tasks in an ecs load balancer
I have a websocket sitting on an AWS ECS instance, in the websocket, there is an endpoint to update an object in the database, which I then want to send the updated result back to all the listeners on the websocket.
The issue is that when this is load balanced, there may be multiple tasks, so when somone updates a record in the database, I need a way to notify all other tasks of this, so that they can be sent through to all websockets
I thought sns would be the solution here, and I could have each task listening to the SNS, however the issue is that SNS will just call an http endpoint, which would go through the load balancer so only one task will recieve an update, not all of them.
Is there something im missing here, or any other technologies I should consider for this? Thanks

some databases have an eventing framework.  Sounds like your servers area all connected to the same database, so that might be the easiest path.  If you happen to be using postgres for example, which is a fantastic db, it has NOTIFY and LISTEN.  I've used them in the past for websocket event pushes and it worked perfectly.

Depends how much you want your architecture to be tied to AWS. You can go with SNS and couple it with a SQS while your websocket workers register to a topic. Or, if you prefer a non-AWS solution, go with a self managed message queue+workers. In my opinion, responsibilities should be separate and the DB mustn't be involved. Scaling, monitoring and debugging become expensive, otherwise.

How would the SQS queue work? if you had all the ecs tasks polling from an sqs queue, once one task picks it up, then the other tasks wont be able to pick it up off the queue no?

The Postgres stuff looks interesting, ill look into that a bit more

I looked into the Postgres, and got an example working, looks really good, think ill proceed with that one, thanks
